# Connection to Neo4j is failing with BoltSecurityError: [SSLCertVerificationError]

Tags: python, python-3.x, neo4j, graph-databases

I have a python script with the following code:

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
from neo4j.debug import watch
watch("neo4j")

uri = "neo4j+s://XXX.databases.neo4j.io:7687"
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=("neo4j", "password"))
```

I run the script in my local computer. The connection fails with the following logs:

```
[DEBUG   ] [Thread 140704683963968] [Task 4387747392     ] 2023-09-07 09:16:20,583  [#0000]  _: <POOL> created, routing address IPv4Address(('XXX.databases.neo4j.io', 7687))
[DEBUG   ] [Thread 140704683963968] [Task 4387747392     ] 2023-09-07 09:16:20,583  [#0000]  _: <WORKSPACE> resolve home database
[DEBUG   ] [Thread 140704683963968] [Task 4387747392     ] 2023-09-07 09:16:20,583  [#0000]  _: <POOL> attempting to update routing table from IPv4Address(('XXX.databases.neo4j.io', 7687))
[DEBUG   ] [Thread 140704683963968] [Task 4387747392     ] 2023-09-07 09:16:20,583  [#0000]  _: <RESOLVE> in: XXX.databases.neo4j.io:7687
[DEBUG   ] [Thread 140704683963968] [Task 4387747392     ] 2023-09-07 09:16:20,695  [#0000]  _: <RESOLVE> dns resolver out: xx.xx.xxx.xx:7687
[DEBUG   ] [Thread 140704683963968] [Task 4387747392     ] 2023-09-07 09:16:20,696  [#0000]  _: <POOL> _acquire router connection, database=None, address=ResolvedIPv4Address(('xx.xx.xxx.xx', 7687))
[DEBUG   ] [Thread 140704683963968] [Task 4387747392     ] 2023-09-07 09:16:20,696  [#0000]  _: <POOL> trying to hand out new connection
[DEBUG   ] [Thread 140704683963968] [Task 4387747392     ] 2023-09-07 09:16:20,701  [#0000]  C: <OPEN> xx.xx.xxx.xx:7687
[DEBUG   ] [Thread 140704683963968] [Task 4387747392     ] 2023-09-07 09:16:20,735  [#EA4B]  C: <SECURE> XXX.databases.neo4j.io
[DEBUG   ] [Thread 140704683963968] [Task 4387747392     ] 2023-09-07 09:16:20,777  [#0000]  S: <CONNECTION FAILED> BoltSecurityError: [SSLCertVerificationError] Connection Failed. Please ensure that your database is listening on the correct host and port and that you have enabled encryption if required. Note that the default encryption setting has changed in Neo4j 4.0. See the docs for more information. Failed to establish encrypted connection. (code 1: Operation not permitted)
```

Specifically:

```
BoltSecurityError: [SSLCertVerificationError] Connection Failed. Please ensure that your database is listening on the correct host and port and that you have enabled encryption if required. Note that the default encryption setting has changed in Neo4j 4.0. See the docs for more information. Failed to establish encrypted connection. (code 1: Operation not permitted)
```

It's very strange that using the same URI and credentials I'm able to connect using the desktop app Neo4j Desktop from my computer.[image]

But for some reason the code fails... any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

(On Mac) I went to the Applications folder, then Python folder and opened "Install Certificates.command"

Not sure why I had to do this manually but it could be the way I initially installed python on my computer.